# Unmark as foldable

Tags: folding, mark

I have recently discovered that it is possible to visually select and mark that selection as foldable through `zf`. I tend to use `zM` & `zR` to toggle the whole foldable text. However, sometimes I want to an area not to fold.

Is it possible to "unmark" a foldable text? Or mark as non-foldable, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's already answered on `:help *fold-delete-marker`:

```
"zd" can be used to delete a fold defined by markers.
```